# Deriving length function from List in data class

Tags: generics, haskell

I have a data class that consists of two aliases: `String` and `[String]`, i.e. `[Char]` and `[[Char]]`. Currently it derives `Eq` and `Show`:

```
data BashVar = BashString String | BashArray [String] deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Why can’t it derive also from `[_]` or however the generic list type is called?

I just want to be able to use list functions on instances of the class, specifically `length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Eq` and `Show` are *typeclasses*, while `[]` is a *data type*.  If you look at the type of `(==)`, it's `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, while `length` is `[a] -> Int`.  The difference is that the first one has a typeclass constraint `Eq a`, and the second one doesn't depend on a typeclass constraint at all, merely on the data type `[a]`.  Unfortunately, there's no way to make the default `length` work with custom data types.

Your best bet is to defined your own functions:

```
bashLength :: BashVar -> Int
bashLength (BashString s) = length s
bashLength (BashArray xs) = length xs
```

Comment: that’s what i’m doing right now, but it looks extremely silly: i have something that’s definitely a list, but in order to call a list function on it, i have to check which kind of list it is before applying the generic list function anyway. it’s like asking if someone wants apples or oranges before giving them fruit salad containing both.

Comment: @flyingsheep That's one of the pitfalls of using algebraic data types.  You defined a type that can be either a string or a list of strings, but you still want to use list functions where its a list and string functions when its a string.  While this layer can be very useful, sometimes it means you have functions that don't make as much "intuitive" sense.

Comment: “string function” doesn’t make sense here: “length” is a list function, since in haskell, `String` is interchangeable with `[Char]`. this means that we execute the exact same machine code in each branch. s is a list, xs is a list: same thing. that’s my problem here: haskell forces me to make a completely unnecessary step of distinguishing between the irrelevant detail of the type of list elements while i just want to count those elements regardless of what they are.

Comment: @flyingsheep The problem is that if you added another constructor `BashInt Int`, then you wouldn't be able to derive any sort of `length` function.  Or worse, you could have a constructor like `DoubleList [String] [String]`, in which case it's impossible to automatically derive `length`, even though `DoubleList` contains a list value.  There are a lot of subtleties to this problem, particularly with algebraic types.  I know it's frustrating but I would argue that as of right now, whenever I see `length`, I know that the argument is _always_ of type `[a]`, rather than a custom type.

Comment: but while i get that an algebraic type is a separate thing instead of the greatest common denominator of the types which it defines aliases for, the derive mechanism allows to specify certain type classes. and i don’t get why haskell wasn’t designed in a way that i can derive from concrete types the same way i could i could from a type class if there were one. haskell knows i can call length on the contents of both, just like show. why can’t i tell it that i want to do it?

Comment: @flyingsheep I would really recommend watching this talk on how typeclasses are implemented in Haskell http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MDCC-TechTalk-Classes-Jim-but-not-as-we-know-them.  Don't worry, it's given to a room of C# devs, so it doesn't go into much of the fiddly details and is very easy to understand.  It really made haskell typeclasses "click" for me, and it might explain the true difference between a typeclass and a datatype, and how Haskell treats them.

Comment: ... @flyingsheep I would also point out that when you derive a typeclass instance, what is happening is that GHC automatically writes the boilerplate code to do this (if you compile with -ddump-deriv flag, you can see this code).  Where ever you have a concrete type in a data constructor (including a type variable like in `[a]`), it checks if that type has an instance for the class you are deriving.  Then it simply pattern matches to extract those fields. For example, if you derive `Eq`, it looks for all types that have the `Eq` instance, extracts them, and applies `==` on them.

Comment: What would it even mean to derive from a concrete type?

Comment: @Brandon The video I posted above might give you an idea of how typeclasses are converted into a parameterized data types, and an instance of the type class is literally a value that is an instance of the corresponding data type.  It's a bit difficult to explain in the confines of comment box, though.  The video fully explains the mechanism of typeclasses, and touches on deriving, but I feel that knowing how typeclasses works really explains how deriving works.

Answer (score 8):

There is no class for lists.  `length` is defined simply as:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

Not (as I think you imagine):

```
class ListLike l where
  length :: l a -> Int
```

The closest class to list is probably `Foldable`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html  But that doesn't define `length`, just various folds.

Besides which, if there was a list class, it would probably still allow the inner type to vary, as in my example above.  Your `BashVar` class doesn't allow any type in the lists, it's fixed to lists of String.  So even if `ListLike` existed, you couldn't support it (and you can't derive `Foldable` for the same reason).

Comment: i don’t quite understand the second part: certainly BashVar is an instance of `[a]` where `a` can be either `Char` or `String` (since `String` is an alias of `[Char]`). but am i right that the first part means that there is no way to make `length` work with BashVar except from hiding the builtin one and importing/writing a new one?

Comment: @flyingsheep: no. `BashVar` is just a data type on its own, not an instance of anything like `[a]`. It does _contain_ values of such types, but that's something completely different. In OO languages "inheriting from some class" and "being a composite of objects from that class" may seem similar, but Haskell makes a very strong distinction between those concepts.

Comment: Note that length can be defined with only Foldable: `length = getSum . foldMap Sum`

Comment: well, but doesn’t `derive(Eq,Show)` work by checking if each class in the composite is a implementation of both Eq and Show, and then enabling the use of functions which take “Eqs” or “Shows” on the composite class?

Answer (score 1):

From your question and comments, where you say a nonsense like the following:

- `I have a data class`
- `Why can’t it derive also from [_] or however the generic list type is called?`
- `BashVar is an instance of [a]`

it's easy to detect that you're trying to "jump" the language without spending the least amount of time at reading even the most basic tutorials.

Getting yourself acquainted at least with the ["Types and Typeclasses" chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) of "Learn You a Haskell" should erase all the questions you've asked here. It would be merely impossible to explain things otherwise, because the language and most of its concepts are way too different from any OOP language you may be trying to project on it.

Comment: i’m merely asking if there is a way to use list functions on things that i know are lists, because i figured there must be a way i’ve missed while reading up on the topic when trying to figure out the solution myself before asking. btw, i’ve learned SML before, so i’m familiar with many concepts of functional programming in general and haskell in particular (SML pretty much *is* haskell without monads. everything works exactly the same except for some minor syntactical differences and explicit instead of implicit lazyness)

Answer (score 1):

So your datatype can be either an array of strings or a single string? What do you want your length function to return?
If you do

```
bashLength :: BashVar -> Int
bashLength (BashString s) = length s
bashLength (BashArray xs) = length xs
```

you get either the length of the string:

```
Main> bashLength (BashString "hello")
5
```

or the length of the array:

```
Main> bashLength (BashArray ["1","2","3"])
3
```

So both cases are in fact very different in meaning.
Is that what you want? It is not a very list-like behaviour. Look at the implementation of the list datatype and the length function, if you want to dive more into this:
http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html

If you just want your type to behave exactly like a list of strings, you could use a type synonym and get all the functions of the list type for free:

```
type BashVar = [String]
```

Or you could try a recursive datatype, in the same way the list type is defined, to mimick the list behaviour:

```
data BashVar = BashString String | BashArray [BashVar] deriving (Show)
```

Now, I would make bashLength just return the length of the array - but I'm not sure if that's what you want to express:

```
bashLength :: Num a => BashVar -> a
bashLength (BashString s) = 1
bashLength (BashArray xs) = sum (map bashLength xs)
```

Let's try it:

```
Main> bashLength(BashArray [])
0
Main> bashLength(BashArray [BashString "b",BashString "c"])
2
```

Still, if you use this approach, you have to name your function "bashLength" or something like that, because "length" is already defined on lists, and overloading of functions in Haskell works via type classes. The list type, at least in in Haskell 98, is a datatype, not a type class whose functions you could implement in your own datataype "BashVar".
To circumvent this limitation, there are even more tricks than wrapping the list type in your own datatype, in case you want to read more:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_instance

Comment: to answer your question if the first `bashLength` is what i want: yes it is, and it’s what i already have right now. in bash, `${#name}` means “characters in `$name`” if `$name` holds a string, and “strings/elements in `$name`” if `$name` holds an array. so my definition of `BashVar` and `bashLength` is correct in that it faithfully represents a bash variable (which can be a string or a list of strings) and the behavior of `#` (which is dependent of that type, as i described)

Comment: Aha, then the answer of @bheklilr contains enough information to solve your problem, hehe. The link I added is maybe still useful, it provides some explanation about why we cannot just inherit the length function from the list type / how to circumvent this problem.

Comment: yeah, as i said: that’s character-for-character the exact same thing that i already wrote myself before asking :D. thank you very much for the link, it’s indeed very interesting! but i consider the lack of a list typeclass a  severe design smell.